# How to avoid duplicate elements in slice in json validation?

Tags: validation, go, golang-migrate

Although I am not a pro-Golang developer, I am trying to restrict the duplicate elements from my array in struct during JSON validation.

```
type Test struct {
Test []*string `json:"test" validate:"required,min=1,max=10,excludes=duplicate"`
}
```

I am using excludes parameter but it's not working for me.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific package?

Answer (score 5):

For array & slices you should use the `unique` tag.

```
type Test struct {
    Test []*string `json:"test" validate:"required,min=1,max=10,unique"`
}
```

Checking the docs:

> For arrays & slices, unique will ensure that there are no duplicates

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator#hdr-Unique

Answer (score 0):

There's this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48298

Which will add a JSON "DisallowDuplicateFields" to the Go standard library.